# If a matrix A has eigenvalues and eigenvectors, then it is invertible

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

can I suppose that ? or there can be times when it's not true.
I know that the eigenvalues of A are : 5,1,1,2,2,2.

Comment: What do you mean with "eigenvalue value"?

Comment: @JonasLenz I edited my question

Comment: @Avital Funk You should assume $0$ is no eigenvalue

Comment: What do you know on $det(A)$ and on the relation between the determinant and invertibility?

Comment: I know that the rank of A is 6 @JonasLenz

Comment: In Your case the determinat is $\det (A)=5\cdot 1\cdot 2^3=40$ as can be seen e.g. from the Jordan normal form, so $A$ is invertible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general $A$ this is of course not true, take for example $A=0$.
We know that the determinant of $A$ is equal to the product of eigenvalues, when you count them as often as the dimension of their generalized eigenspaces implies.
Hence, in your special case we have $det(A)=40\not =0$ which shows that $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

$A $ is invertible if  and only if  $0$ is not an eigenvalue of  $A $.